# How can I tell i'm compiling on a mac?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I'm using a compiled-from-source gcc for the avr. My gcc configure options are:

```
${PWD}/../gcc/configure --prefix="${PWD}/../build/" --exec-prefix="${PWD}/../build/" --datadir="${PWD}/../build/" --target=avr --enable-languages=c --disable-libssp --disable-lto --disable-nls --disable-libgomp --disable-gdbtk --disable-threads --enable-poison-system-directories
```

When I use the following snippet of preprocessor magic

```
#if defined __APPLE__
#error "Apple"
#else
#error "Ahh"
#endif
```

it is outputting

```
error: #error "Ahh"
```

If I run `avr-cpp -dM version.h` I see `__APPLE__` is not defined. If I run `cpp -dM version.h` I see that `__APPLE__` is defined. What do I have to change in my configure line (or elsewhere) to get my compiled-from-source gcc to have `__APPLE__` defined correctly?

I'm on a mac compiling for the avr as apposed to being on windows compiling for the avr.

Answer (score 0):

Probably all you can potentially need is [HERE](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php)

and specifically about Mac [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Operating_Systems#MacOS)

Comment: I'm checking for `__APPLE__`  its not defined, `avr-cpp -dM version.h` doesn't list it either, `cpp -dM version.h` does. So, something in my build of gcc made it not be defined.